# How to maintain state between Nuxt.js frontend and Laravel backend

Tags: php, laravel, vuex, nuxt.js

I have a Laravel backend which I want to pair with a separate Nuxt frontend. Both are still fairly empty projects (a new Laravel app and basic Nuxt template), so all options are still on the table.

I want to maintain as little state as possible in the frontend, such that the session data (logged in user, language setting and perhaps some other things) persists through page refreshes and browser tabs.

For the backend, this seems fairly straightforward: just use the Laravel session to store data like you normally would with any Laravel application.

However, for the frontend, I don't immediately see what the best option would be. It seems to me like using middleware would work well, but I'm not sure how to best implement it.

I know this is a somewhat broad question, but I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle this via localstorage. Vuex works great for this. You can have a listener that save the entire state to localstorage whenever any changes occur.
Then you just load the state from localstorage when the page loads. This way your state persists throughout page refreshes and tabs.

Comment: the question is nuxt, and nuxt is not great with localstorage

Comment: @AndresFelipe I use this apporach with nuxt without any issues